# RethinkDB / Horizon: Integration with Express: Access Horizon data server-side?

Tags: node.js, rethinkdb, horizon

There is an example of express integration on the Horizon.io Github as shown here:
[Horizon express server example](https://github.com/rethinkdb/horizon/tree/next/examples/express-server)

I understand what this example is showing: if you have an existing Express server you can add a horizon server, which exposes a route client-side so they can connect to horizon server via websockets.

**However, is there is any way for the express part of the server to also access the collections in Horizon?** For example, to do things like local authentication, CRON jobs, or have API endpoints that accept PUT/POST requests.

From what I understand, a direct connection to the RethinkDB database Horizon is using is not that useful, because of a library named Fusion that is dynamically setting metadata on the tables in order to get Firebase-like behavior that Horizon is used for.

**How can I access Horizon data server-side?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access the collections of Horizon you can use the @horizon/client.

```
npm install --save  @horizon/client
```

in server side code:

```
const Horizon = require("@horizon/client/dist/horizon");
const horizon = Horizon();
```

And then you can use the Horizon API:http://horizon.io/api/horizon/ for things such as connection, Auth, and users; then use the collection API: http://horizon.io/api/collection/ for getting access to the same collections that the client accesses.

Comment: And is there a way to create a custom endpoint? Or share that data somehow with the client?

Comment: I tried this and found it was failing silently...

But it looks like the next version of the client will fix it and allow you to just `require('@horizon/client')` instead.

Made some notes here: https://github.com/joshwnj/knowledge/blob/master/horizon-in-node/index.md

Answer (score 1):

You need to create express/koa/hapi server, where you include horizon/server and provide your own implementation for custom API endpoints.

Read more here: http://horizon.io/docs/embed/