# horizion connect to an existing expressjs app results in 400 bad request

Tags: express, rethinkdb, horizon

I try to connect from my htmlpage to my expressjs app over horizon.

My server is like this [https://github.com/rethinkdb/horizon/blob/next/examples/express-server/main.js]:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
'use strict'

const express = require('express');
const horizon = require('@horizon/server');

const app = express();
const http_server = app.listen(8181);
const options = { auth: { token_secret: 'my_super_secret_secret' } };
const horizon_server = horizon(http_server, options);

app.use(express.static('public'));

console.log('Listening on port 8181.');
```

Then i followed this link: http://horizon.io/docs/getting-started/#integrating-horizon-with-an-existing-application
and created the following html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="http://localhost:8181/horizon/horizon.js"></script>
    <script>
      var horizon = Horizon({host: 'localhost:8181'});
      horizon.onReady(function() {
        document.querySelector('h1').innerHTML = 'App works!'
      });
      horizon.connect();
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <marquee><h1></h1></marquee>
  </body>
</html>
```

my package.json dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@horizon/server": "^1.0.3",
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "horizon": "^1.0.3"
  }
```

it results in an 400 error:

polling-xhr.js:250GET http://localhost:8181/horizon/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LJke5oP 400 (Bad Request)

index.js:66Received an error: Error: Websocket ws://localhost:8181 experienced an error

Whats wrong, how do i get a valid connection to my express backend?
I saw this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37402526/rethinkdb-horizon-integration-with-express-access-horizon-data-server-side) but i dont know if it is the same problem.

**Update**
I created a [repository](https://github.com/svenhornberg/stackhorizionexpress) for my question and asked the same question on the [projectpage](https://discuss.horizon.io/t/connect-to-an-existing-expressjs-app-results-in-400-bad-request/217).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Info: seems to be a [bug](https://github.com/rethinkdb/horizon/issues/525#issuecomment-222103680) and should be fixed in the next release.